# Collections error when testing a many:many self relationship in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails API with a many to many self relationship.

Sentence Model

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :sentence_sentences
   has_many :related_sentences, 
            :through => :sentence_sentences
end
```

SentenceSentence Model

```
class SentenceSentence < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sentence
   belongs_to :related_sentence, :class_name => 'Sentence'
end
```

sentences Rspec factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :sentence do
      sentence "I put most constants in a plain text file, and then go through a massive indentation cleanup"
      language "en"
      user
   end

   factory :related_sentence, class: Sentence do
      sentence "Je ai mis la plupart des constantes dans un fichier texte, puis passe par un nettoyage massif d'indentation"
  language "fr"
   end
end
```

Model spec

```
RSpec.describe Sentence, type: :model do
   let(:sentence) { FactoryGirl.build :sentence }
   subject { sentence }

 describe "related sentences associations" do
  before do
     @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  end

  it "allows the same user to create a related sentence" do
     related_sentence = FactoryGirl.build(:related_sentence)
     related_sentence.user_id = @user.id
     sentence.related_sentences = related_sentence   
     expect(Sentence.find(sentence.related_sentence).user_id).to eql user.id
  end
end
```

But I am getting an error when I run Rspec

```
 1) Sentence related sentences associations allows the same user to     create a related sentence
     Failure/Error: sentence.related_sentences = related_sentence
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for #<Sentence:0x0000000661db30>
```

**EDIT** After modifing the test to check for how many related_senteces are created, I am getting none.

```
describe "related sentences associations" do
    before do
       @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    end

    it "allows the same user to create a related sentence" do
       related_sentence = FactoryGirl.build(:related_sentence)
       related_sentence.user_id = @user.id
       sentence.related_sentences << related_sentence   
       expect(sentence.related_sentences.count).to eql 1
    end
 end
```

Test results

```
 1) Sentence related sentences associations allows the same user to create a related sentence
     Failure/Error: expect(sentence.related_sentences.count).to eql 1

       expected: 1
            got: 0

       (compared using eql?)
```

Comment: You missed a "s" on `related_sentence` or you should use `<<` instead of `=`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... but I don't understand. Could you please post the correct code?

Comment: I am a bit unsure on exactly what you are trying to accomplish. but your sentence class does not have a method `related_sentence`

Comment: in answer to your edit. Try `sentence.reload` on the line above the expect.

Comment: Thanks @Albin sentence.save did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do the trick

```
it "allows the same user to create a related sentence" do
  related_sentence = FactoryGirl.build(:related_sentence)
  related_sentence.user_id = @user.id
  sentence.related_sentences << related_sentence   

  expect(Sentence.find(sentence.related_sentences.last).user_id).to eql user.id
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to test that it is possible to create a related sentence using the many:many relationship.

Comment: I think this will test that.